# parent directive scope → child directive scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i have angularjs problem.

I want like ng-repeat at $index.

- this is ng-repeat code  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L3

look at the function 'updateScope'

```
var updateScope = function(scope, index, valueIdentifier, value, keyIdentifier, key, arrayLength){
    // TODO(perf): generate setters to shave off ~40ms or 1-1.5%
    scope[valueIdentifier] = value;
    if (keyIdentifier) scope[keyIdentifier] = key;
    scope.$index = index;
    scope.$first = (index === 0);
    scope.$last = (index === (arrayLength - 1));
    scope.$middle = !(scope.$first || scope.$last);
    // jshint bitwise: false
    scope.$odd = !(scope.$even = (index&1) === 0);
    // jshint bitwise: true
};
```

this code action 
'parent directive scope variables -> child directive scope variables'

and you can do this

```
ng-repeat(...)
    {{$index}}
```

I want this action!!

I try, but do not action

this is my code

-jade

```
m-progressbar(min="0", max="300", ng-model="value")
    label {{$ratio}}
```

-js

```
$scope.value=72;
```

-directive

```
define([
    'jquery', 'underscore', 'angular', 'jquery-ui'],
function ($, _, angular) {
    var progressbarApp = angular.module('directives.progress_bar', []);
    progressbarApp
    .directive('mProgressbar', [function mProgressbar () {
     return {
            templateUrl: '/directives/progress-bar.jade',
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: {
                min: '=',
                max: '=',
                model: "=ngModel"
            },
            link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                var progressbar = $( "#progressbar" ); 
                var value = scope.model;
                scope.$watch('model',function (newValue, oldValue, scope){
                    var ratio = ((newValue - scope.min) / (scope.max - scope.min)) * 100;
                    progressbar.progressbar({value:ratio});
                    scope.$ratio = ratio;
                });
            }
        };
    }]) 
});
```

my code point is

- scope.$ratio = ratio;

please tell me a answer
ㅠoㅠ

Answer (score 0):

I think you just forgot to add $ before ratio if you want to use {{$ratio}} in your template.
I mean you should write like below.

```
scope.$ratio = ratio;
```